# Am i doing this Differential Equation (exponential function) properly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question: A differential equation is given by $y''-5y'=xe^{5x}$. Given that a particular solution is $y_p(x)=Ax^2e^{5x}+Bxe^{5x}$, solve the diferential equation.

I attempted the question and this is what I have [so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbmOU.png)

I'm not sure how to proceed with the rest of the question, any tips?

Comment: Just need to solve $y'' - 5y' = 0.$ Then the solution is the solution of this equation $+$ the particular solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions the the homogenous problem and $y_p$ is any particular solution, then $y = c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2 + y_p$ is the general solution.

To this end, we solve $Ly := y'' - 5y' = 0$. The indical equation is $$r^2 - 5r = 0 \iff r(r-5) = 0 \iff r = 0, 5.$$

Thus, the general solution is $y = c_1 + c_2 e^{5t} + Ax^2e^{5x} + Bxe^{5x}$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants to be determined by substation of $y_p$ into the ODE.